# How to convert system.intptr to int

Tags: .net, visual-studio, int

I have a problem with compiling the program in visual studio. Please help.

...

```
else
{
    string str4 = strArrays1[i];
    chrArray = new char[] { ':' };
    strArrays = str4.Split(chrArray);
    string str5 = strArrays[0];
    string str6 = "";
    for (j = 1; j < (int)strArrays.Length; j++)
    {
        str6 = string.Concat(str6, strArrays[j]);
        if (j < (int)strArrays.Length - 1)
        {
            string[] strArrays3 = strArrays;
            string[] strArrays4 = strArrays3;
            int num1 = j;
            IntPtr intPtr = (IntPtr)num1;
            strArrays3[num1] = string.Concat(strArrays4[intPtr], ":");
        }
    }
    this.hashTable[str5] = str6;
}
```

...

The problem occurs in the line:

```
strArrays3 [num1] = string.Concat (strArrays4 [intPtr], ":");
```

Error:

CS0266  C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IntPtr' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Um. Why are you using IntPtr for a loop indexer? Normally that would just be an int.

Comment: I am not the creator of this program, so I will not answer the question. Unfortunately I need to compile it: /

Comment: Please edit the question to include the specific error message.

Comment: CS0266  C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IntPtr' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Based on the vague, type-derived variable names, is this decompiled code you're trying to recompile?  That might explain why that line (and, really, the entire body of the `if` statement) wasn't written as simply `strArrays[j] = string.Concat(strArrays[j], ":");`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast your `IntPtr` to `int` as follows.

```
strArrays3[num1] = string.Concat(strArrays4[(int)intPtr], ":");
```

But you should use an `int` in the first place. You would then not need a cast to `int`.